# Using custom font icons in plotly scatter plot

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to use Font Awesome icons in text annotations of a plotly scatter graph.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[1, 1, 1],
    mode="lines+markers+text",
    name="Lines, Markers and Text",
    text=["Text A", "Text B", "Text C"],
    textposition="top center"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[2, 2, 2],
    mode="markers+text",
    name="Markers and Text",
    text=["Text D", "Text E", "Text F"],
    textposition="bottom center"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[3, 3, 3],
    mode="lines+text",
    name="Lines and Text",
    text=["<i class="fa fa-desktop' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "Text H", "Text I"],
    textposition="bottom center"
))

fig.show()
```

I am  running this plot in a dash app and have font awesome css stored in /assets. If I add a `html.I()` tag in `dash` fonts appear as expected. So how to treat plotly to take care of additional css?

Comment: Is this a question or a working solution?

Comment: It is a question because it does not work to use `html.I()` tags in plotly.

Comment: Then why did you say "If I add a `html.I()` tag fonts appeared as expected". What exactly is happening when you now say "it does not work to use `html.I()` tags in plotly." What error are you getting?

Comment: Ahh thanks for this hint. This was related to using this in a dash environement.